# Python export to a TXT formatted or to Clipboard

Tags: python, export-to-text

I have a csv file that is something like BM13302, EM13203,etc
I have to read this from a file then reformat it to something like 'BM13302', 'EM13203',etc

What I'm having problems with is how do I export (write it either the clipboard or a file, I can cut and paste from.  This is a tiny little project for reformatting some for part of some SQL code that's given to me in a unclean format and i have to spend a little while formatting it out.  I would like to just point python to a directory and past the list in the file and have it export everything that way I need it.

I have the following code working

```
import os
f = open(r"/User/person/Desktop/folder/file.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    print(row)
```

I get the expected results

I would like find out how to take the list(?) and format it like this
    'BM1234', 'BM2351', '20394',....etc
and copy that to the clipboard

I thought something doing something like

```
with open('/Users/person/Desktop/csv/export.txt') as f:
    f.write("open=", + "', '")
f.close()
```

nothing is printed.  Can't find an example of what I'm needing.  Anyone able to help me out??

Much Appreciate!

Comment: to write in file you have to open file in `"write mode"` - ie. `open(..., "w")`

Comment: if you use `with open()` then you don't need `close()`. It will close automatically.

Comment: So all you want to do is put single quotes around each word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the csv module quote things for you. As far as I know there is no clipboard in the python standard libs but there are various mechanisms out there. Here I'm using `pyperclip` which is reasonable for text-only copies.

```
import pyperclip
import csv
import io

def clip_csv(filename):
    outbuf = io.StringIO()
    with open('file.csv', newline='') as infile:
        incsv = csv.reader(infile, skipinitialspace=True)
        outcsv = csv.writer(outbuf, quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        outcsv.writerows(incsv)
    pyperclip.copy(outbuf.getvalue())

clip_csv('file.csv')
# DEBUG: Verify by printing clipboard
print(pyperclip.paste())
```

Comment: Perfect, I was going to use pyperclip but didn't know about io.  Thank you much.  I've made it a little smarter but taking and placing a variable to hold the input of a filename and run as normal, that way it's not always the same static file.
You Rock tdelaney!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you try to add quote char `'` to all data in `csv`

```
import csv

with open('export.csv', 'w') as f:

     # use quote char `'` for all data
     writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

     writer.writerow(["BM1234", "BM2351", "20394"])
```